# Django Rest Framework - Bad request

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to call an API endpoint on my Django project from my frontend.

The endpoint is at the URL `/tst/`. I need to retrieve data from that endpoint, in order to populate my page with that data.

I'm using an ajax request for this, but I keep getting the error `400 - BAD REQUEST`, but I don't know why this happens since the API endpoint is at the right URL.

```
function doPoll(){

    $.post('http://localhost:8000/tst/', function(data) {
        console.log(data[0]);
        $('#data').text( data[0].data);
        setTimeout(doPoll, 10);
    });
}
```

My endpoint's view:

```
class tstList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = tst.objects.using('screener').all()
    serializer_class = tstSerializer
```

**models.py**

```
 class tst(models.Model):
        ticker = models.CharField(max_length=15)
        Price = models.FloatField()

        def save(self, *args, using=None, **kwargs):
            super(tst, self).save(*args, using='screener', **kwargs)
```

The json looks like this:

```
{"ticker":["TEST"],"Price":["4847"]}
```

What I got in the response:

```
{"ticker":["This field is required."],"Price":["This field is required."]}
```

Comment: You're posting to the URL but you're not sending any data. Perhaps you meant to use `$.get`?

Comment: If you get a 400 BAD REQUEST, look at the response's body. It'll have all the explanation why Django REST framework rejected the request.

Comment: @DanielRoseman what do you mean?

Comment: Thanks @Linovia, looking into it right now

Comment: Exactly what I said. You are sending a POST. A post is for *submitting data* to the backend, but you don't send any data; and anyway you want to *retrieve data*. Use `$.get()`.

Comment: Show me your data and model

Comment: @DanielRoseman i can use a GET request, but i read that GET request are not suitable in particular for large amounts of data, or for sensitive data

Comment: added it @mamuncode

Comment: For *submitting* those things. You are not submitting data. Use a get.

Comment: Ok, thanks @DanielRoseman! And how can i make it so that the data is updated every X seconds, without reloading the page and without a user action?

Comment: Isn't that what this code does already?

Comment: Yeah, but i'll have to re-make it, so that it's a GET request instead

Comment: Literally, just replace `$.post` wth `$.get`. No other changes needed.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend utilizing Axios for the HTTP request call instead of ajax.
Axios: https://github.com/axios/axios

Looks like, you have to implement get request in your end-points view.

```
class tstList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
  queryset = tst.objects.using('screener').all()
  serializer_class = tstSerializer
  
  def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```